# Cannot kill buffer: "Marker does not point anywhere"

Tags: emacs

I am using [dired-sidebar](https://github.com/jojojames/dired-sidebar) and for some reason I cannot kill it's buffer, as a result I cannot quit Emacs, it ends up always in error `save-places-to-alist: Marker does not point anywhere`. May be it is plugin problem, or my configurations problem, I will investigate this. The question is how can I close Emacs gracefully in this situation?

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Marker does not point anywhere")
dired-current-directory()
save-place-to-alist()
kill-buffer(#<buffer :~/.config/zsh/>)
kill-this-buffer()
eval((kill-this-buffer) nil)
eval-expression((kill-this-buffer))
eval((eval-expression (car-safe (read-from-string #("(kill-this-buffer)" 0 1 (ex-index 1) 1 2 (ex-index 2) 2 3 (ex-index 3) 3 4 (ex-index 4) 4 5 (ex-index 5) 5 6 (ex-index 6) 6 7 (ex-index 7) 7 8 (ex-index 8) 8 9 (ex-index 9) 9 10 (ex-index 10) 10 11 (ex-index 11) 11 12 (ex-index 12) 12 13 (ex-index 13) 13 14 (ex-index 14) 14 15 (ex-index 15) 15 16 (ex-index 16) 16 17 (ex-index 17) 17 18 (ex-index 18))))))
(if evil-ex-expression (eval evil-ex-expression) (user-error "Ex: syntax error"))
(if (= 0 (length result)) nil (if evil-ex-expression (eval evil-ex-expression) (user-error "Ex: syntax error")))
evil-ex-execute(#("(kill-this-buffer)" 0 1 (ex-index 1) 1 2 (ex-index 2) 2 3 (ex-index 3) 3 4 (ex-index 4) 4 5 (ex-index 5) 5 6 (ex-index 6) 6 7 (ex-index 7) 7 8 (ex-index 8) 8 9 (ex-index 9) 9 10 (ex-index 10) 10 11 (ex-index 11) 11 12 (ex-index 12) 12 13 (ex-index 13) 13 14 (ex-index 14) 14 15 (ex-index 15) 15 16 (ex-index 16) 16 17 (ex-index 17) 17 18 (ex-index 18)))
(let ((evil-ex-current-buffer (current-buffer)) (evil-ex-previous-command (if initial-input nil (car-safe evil-ex-history))) evil-ex-argument-handler evil-ex-info-string result) (let ((fun (if initial-input (function evil-ex-setup-and-update) (function evil-ex-setup))) setup-hook) (setq setup-hook (function (lambda nil (remove-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook) (funcall fun)))) (unwind-protect (progn (add-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook) (setq result (read-from-minibuffer ":" (or initial-input (and evil-ex-previous-command ...)) evil-ex-completion-map nil (quote evil-ex-history) evil-ex-previous-command t))) (remove-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook))) (evil-ex-execute result))
evil-ex(nil)
funcall-interactively(evil-ex nil)
call-interactively(evil-ex nil nil)
command-execute(evil-ex)
```

Comment: Did you try to examine the stack trace to see where the error may be coming from? Try `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and recreate the error. That could give folks here a better idea how to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have updated.

Comment: Sorry it was not complete at the time.

Comment: Hm, I'm not really familiar with Emacs' internals so when I looked at the code over there I didn't see anything that would do something with markers. Maybe you hit a bug and want to submit it? Sorry I can't help more with this.